# Docker network create -d transparent failed

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a transparent network on my docker host in order to directly connect to the physical network. However, when I ran the following command, I got this error:

```
docker network create -d "transparent" --subnet 192.168.100.0/24 --gateway 192.168.100.1 mytransparentnet
Error response from daemon: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The parameter is incorrect. (0x57)
```

I've been searching the root cause about this issue the whole afternoon, but can't find any solutions. Hope someone can help give me some suggestion. Thanks!

### Environment:

OS: Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.1110

Docker Version: Docker Engine - Community V20.10.7 (Hyper-V backend)